# Allowing function shortcut keys during message box popup

Tags: c#, messagebox

When a user enters an incorrect value, a message box will show up and read "Entry not a match. Do you want to overwrite?". When this message box appears, I would like for the user to be able to hit the F1 key and have a separate page show when this shows up without them having to close the message box. Is this possible with the way I have my code or do I need to restructure this whole deal?

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Entry not a match. Do you want to overwrite?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                {   //below is the code I want to use as the shortcut for when the messae box appears if it is possible to do it this way

if (e.Key == Key.F1)
        {
            viewEntry page = new viewEntry ();
            page.textBox.Text = textBox.Text;
            page.ShowDialog();
        }
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Confirm Overwrite", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        //do something

                    }
                    tnImage.Text = "✓";
                    tnImage.FontSize = 22;
                    tnImage.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    txtTN.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    txtBN.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: I think you would have to implement your own custom `MessageBox` which allows you to press the F1 key and display another window

Comment: Thats what I figured but wasnt sure if I could get by with this way